# Computing Confidence in A/B testing

Tags: beta-distribution, uncertainty, decision-theory, ab-test

First of all, I'm fairly new to Decision Theory and my question might be rather too simple for the experts.

I am having some issues in computing confidence for A/B Testing. I will first explain the scenario and then the technique to compute confidence.

It's a typical scenario extending from clinical trials, where I test two headlines for an article to see which one's doing better. Let's say that I have two headlines and I do the A/B test for 20 minutes and see which one is better and by how much confidence. I compute the CTRs of the headlines (= clicks/views) after 20 minutes and see if there's a "significant" difference between the two. I use the Anscombe quartet for that and if the difference in CTRs is significant enough, I pick a winning headline.

To compute the confidence, I model the CTRs of the headlines as beta distributions with $\alpha = ($VIEWS$_a \times$ CTR$_a)$ and $\beta = ($VIEWS$_a \times (1 - $CTR$_a))$, which obviously assumes that the prior is a uniform distribution. Once I have the two beta distributions, I compute the confidence using Monte Carlo Sampling of the two distributions. I set my cut-off as 80% for the overlap to be able to "confidently" tell that one headline is better than the other.

However, since the kurtosis of the beta distribution increases non-linearly, for a given CTR, it increases non-linearly with the number of views. So, for very small differences in CTRs, I can end up with very high confidence if the number of views is very high for a given article. Is there anything I can do to fix this? Use some other distribution with some other confidence measure? I also want the distribution to make good intuitive sense and I'm not really sure if Beta is the best that I can choose for this.

Thanks in advance!